# 'Nonetype' object is not subscriptable - From outlook API extraction

Tags: python, anaconda, outlook-restapi

I have some code that connects directly to outlook and extracts metadata from an inbox then complies into a pandas. However, I seem to be getting an error which I haven't encountered before and I suspect it has to do with bad data in the outlook extraction (i.e. blank data on an email). But I can't seem to isolate. Has anyone seen this before?

```
ERROR:app:Exception on /ctplive [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\ADM\Code Projects\web_data_connector\outlook_api\app.py", line 100, in mailbox_insights
    inbox['Conversation Length'] = determine_conversation_length(inbox['ConversationIndex'], archive['ConversationIndex']).astype(int).values
  File "c:\users\adm\code projects\ccf_email_automation\ccf_email_automation\insights.py", line 92, in determine_conversation_length
    res[index] = len([x[:len(index)] for x in list(inbox_index) + list(archive_index) if x[:len(index)] == index])
  File "c:\users\adm\code projects\ccf_email_automation\ccf_email_automation\insights.py", line 92, in <listcomp>
    res[index] = len([x[:len(index)] for x in list(inbox_index) + list(archive_index) if x[:len(index)] == index])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is the block from app.py

```
    if mailbox not in ['ctp', 'csu', 'dmt']:
        return 404
    archive, inbox = get_emails(mailbox, get_outlook())
    inbox['Sender'] = inbox[['SenderName', 'SenderEmailAddress']].apply(lambda x: read_email_address(*x), axis=1)
    inbox['Sender Domain'] = inbox['SenderEmailAddress'].apply(lambda x: x[x.index('@') + 1:] if '@' in x else 'gilead.com')
    inbox['TABL_Highest Volume Senders'] = top_senders(inbox)
    inbox['TABL_Highest Volume Sender Domains'] = top_sender_domains(inbox)
    *************line 100 starts here**************
    inbox['Conversation Length'] = determine_conversation_length(inbox['ConversationIndex'], archive['ConversationIndex']).astype(int).values
    inbox['TABL_Longest Conversations'] = longest_conversations(inbox['Conversation Length'])
    holiday_list = get_holidays()
    inbox['Business Day SLA'] = inbox[['Received Date', 'Flag Completed Date']].apply(lambda x: calculate_sla(*x, holiday_list=holiday_list), axis=1)
    inbox['Team Member'] = hardcode_team_member(inbox, mailbox)
    inbox['Sentiment Score'] = determine_sentiment(inbox['Body'])
    inbox['Flag Status'] = inbox[['Flag Completed Date', 'FlagRequest']].apply(lambda x: flag_status(*x), axis=1)
    inbox['Complexity'] = inbox['Categories'].str.extract(r'Complexity Level (\d)').astype(float)
    inbox['Protocol'] = inbox.pipe(identify_first_protocol)
    inbox['Speed to Market'] = inbox['Categories'].str.contains('Speed to Market')
    return inbox.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_')).drop(columns=['ConversationIndex']).to_json(), 200
```

Here is the block from insights.py:

```
    res = pd.Series(index=inbox_index, dtype='object')
    for index in tqdm(inbox_index):
    *******Line 92 starts here********
        res[index] = len([x[:len(index)] for x in list(inbox_index) + list(archive_index) if x[:len(index)] == index])
    return res
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the code mate?

Comment: Either `res` or `x` is not a list (or other subscriptable type).

Comment: @LibbyLebyane sorry about that, I have added the blocks referenced in the error. Hope that clarifies, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger to see what the values of all variables are at that point? Have you ensured that `pd.Series(index=inbox_index, dtype='object')` is returning something? If you haven't done basic debugging yet, please do. PyCharm is free and has a great debugger: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when working with APIs it's recommended to use `if statements` since you might not be sure what may be returned. Perhaps you can try to check what type `inbox` and `res` is, so your code might look like this:

For insights.py

```py
res = pd.Series(index=inbox_index, dtype='object')
if res: # Check if res actually has a value before subscribing to it with res[key]
    for index in tqdm(inbox_index):
    *******Line 92 starts here********
        res[index] = len([x[:len(index)] for x in list(inbox_index) + list(archive_index) if x[:len(index)] == index])
        return res
```

Then you might as well do the same with the for the `app.py` before using the `inbox` variable, or just use a bunch of `if statements` checking before accessing a data point then handling the error if something is type `NoneType`.

Comment: hmmm, when I do this it returns entire df as null so I don't think it's reviewing any under that if. I will add this issue only started a few days ago and has been working for quite some time. So I suspect it's only one value in the dataset, but I can't figure out how to isolate

Comment: Looks like you have some direction on your issue, at lease you have an idea where the issue might be.